# Type hinting return -> object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting

I have a function to get a SQLAchemy Engine connection:

```
def get_engine_connection(
    username: str,
    password: str,
    database: str,
    host: str = "localhost",
    port: str = "3306",
) -> object:
    try:
        engine = create_engine(
            f"mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}",
            echo=False,
            poolclass=NullPool,
        )
        return engine
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

If all goes well, the return type will be:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>
```

Is it correct for me to say that the return of my function will be an object or is there no type hint object?

```
def get_engine_connection( // ) -> object:
    //
```

Comment: if the try fails, your code will return jack squad

Comment: Why do you want to use `object` (which is not helpful at all) and not `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine` as the the type hint?

Comment: Please read this article :
https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/16/python-type-hints-return-class-not-instance/#:~:text=In%20a%20type%20hint%2C%20if,Type%20).

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type) goes over the `Any` and `object` types. In particular, it says

> Use `object` to indicate that a value could be any type in a typesafe manner. Use `Any` to indicate that a value is dynamically typed.

The return value of your function isn't dynamically typed, so it sounds like `object` is appropriate in this case. However it would be better to use `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine` itself if possible, likely as `type[sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine]` as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73086518/type-hinting-return-object/73086597#comment129082417_73086518).